# Holding a type in a member or return a type from function in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm trying to create a central Events class for my entire events in the system, so developers will just need to navigate over this class to look for the relevant events. my queue messages handlers are generic function that deserialize the events payload by the event-type and the generic parameter, all of information to create such producer is in this "Events Metadata" class/

This is an example to how I think the Events class should look like:

```js
import { AgentConnectedDto } from "./dto/SDP/AgentConnectedDto"
import { AgentDisconnectedDto } from "./dto/SDP/AgentDisconnectedDto"
import AgentConnectedSchema from "./dto/SDP/AgentConnectedDto.Schema.json"
import AgentDisconnectedSchema from "./dto/SDP/AgentDisconnectedDto.Schema.json"

export class Events {
    static AgentService = class {
        static AgentConnected = class {
            static eventName: string = "agent.connected"
            static schema = AgentConnectedSchema
            static dtoType = (): AgentConnectedDto | null => { return null; };
        }

        static AgentDisconnected = class {
            static eventName: string = "agent.disconnected"
            static schema = AgentDisconnectedSchema
            static dtoType = (): AgentDisconnectedDto | null => { return null; };
        }
    }
}
```

and this is how I'm planning to use it:

```js
publish(Events.AgentService.AgentConnected.eventName,
    new Message\<ReturnType\<typeof Events.AgentService.AgentConnected.dtoType\>\> (
        {
            agentId: "",
            userId: "",
            connectionTS: 0
        }),
    Events.AgentService.AgentConnected.schema
);
```

The idea beyond this central class is that the developers just need to know what is the service/domain that is firing the event into the Event bus (i.e. **Events.AgentService**) and just need to look for the relevant event metadata (i.e. eventName, Dto Type and Json Schema) using the IDE IntelliSense.

The problem is that the code is too cumbersome, can I replace the **"ReturnType<typeof Events.AgentService.AgentConnected.dtoType>"** with a simpler alias, can I return just a type from the function or not having a function at all and just return a type?
I need that it will be recognized by the compiler, so the developer will get an immediate feedback for the IDE?

An example of desired code:

```
static AgentConnected = class {
    static eventName: string = "agent.connected"
    static schema = AgentConnectedSchema
    static dtoType = typeof (AgentConnectedDto)
}
```

so no need for:

```js
new Message<<ReturnType<typeof Events.AgentService.AgentConnected.dtoType>>()
```

instead developer will write:

```js
new Message<Events.AgentService.AgentConnected.dtoType>()
```

BTW, the Event class above it being generated from Json Schemas.

Thank you